# Is there a way to use symfony2 entity validations as doctrine validations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a Symfony2 application which uses a few forms. The data from the forms is persisted into a MySQL db using Doctrine2. I set up some constraints on the entities using Symfony annotations. Now, when the user fails to enter appropriate data into a form, he get's an error message, but, when I try to manipulate the same entities using a Command object I don't get any exception or error whatsoever.

From the documentation I read, Symfony's and Doctrine's validation work as separate mechanisms, now... is there a way to to make them work as one? What I'm trying to avoid is writing the same validations for the entity objects in order to use them as frontend and backend validations. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The forms validate automatically when you call `$form->isValid()` but if you want to validate an object outside of a form you have to call it manually.

In your command class just get the `validator` service and validate your object before you persist it.

```
$validator = $this->container->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($myEntity);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    return new Response(print_r($errors, true));
} else {
    return new Response('The entity is valid!');
}
```

More in the documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Comment: I think it helps to mention that the form component internally calls the validation service. I.e. they both work from the same configuration.

Comment: I see... it's kind of frustrating having to either explicitly call validation or write the validation rules twice (And call it explicitly when persisting the objects)...

Comment: I suppose you could add an event listener to doctrine to validate all objects before they are persisted. But otherwise I'm not sure how you would expect it to "automatically" validate without you handling it yourself. In any case you shouldn't have to write the validation twice, though.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration

Click on tab "Annotations" of the sample. You can add validate condition with ORM annotations in the entity